# Batch File: If command is not working

Tags: batch-file

I have this batch file called tst.bat:

```
    @echo off

:_main
   set str=%1

   call :_checkInput
   call :_strLen %str%

   echo %_strLen% 

exit /b

:_checkInput

if "%str:~0,1%" == """ set str=%str:~1%       
if "%str:~-1%" == """ set str=%str:~0,-1%   

goto :eof

:_strLen
   setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
   set str=%1

   :_loop
      if /i "!str:~%len%,1!" neq "" set /a len+= 1 & goto :_loop
   (endlocal & set _strLen=%len%)
goto :eof
```

but for some reason I'm getting an error saying: "set was unexpected at this time." when I typed `tst "Hello"` on the command prompt. The error if from the "IF" command in the _checkInput part.

I will greatly appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for editing Magoo

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use the command modifiers to strip the surrounding quotes? `set str=%~1`

Comment: @Squashman Before Magoo's comment I didn't know that it's possible. :)

Comment: Did you consider opening up a cmd prompt and reading the help from for the call command? Type `call /?` at a cmd prompt.

Comment: The problem in your code is that there is an invalid syntax: your `if` command lines become `if """==""" set ...` when the first expression expands to `"`, so the comparison operator `==` becomes actually quoted, which is not expected; and your `if` command lines become something like `if "?"==""" set ...` when the first expression expands to something else, like `?`, so the last quote and everything (!) after is considered as the second comparison expression, which is also invalid; for such `if` comparisons to work you need to use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suspect, the problem has to do with <kbd>"</kbd>

You can strip enclosing spaces from `%1` using `%~1`.

You can remove all `"` using `set "var=%var:"=%"`

Comment: Add yeah you are right Magoo. This line set "var=%var:"=%" totally replaced my _checkInput. Thank you! I appreciate your help. Cheers!